# To set sort_by in compare function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In Vuejs 2.6 app I use compare function for different sort by `sort_by` :

```
export default {
    data: function () {
        return {
            ...
            sort_by: null,
        }

    },

    computed: {
        ...
        hostelsList: function() {
            if ( this.sort_by == null || typeof this.sort_by == "undefined" ) {
                this.sort_by= 'price' 
            }
            console.log("this.sort_by::")
            console.log( this.sort_by )


            function compare(a, b) {
                if ( this.sort_by == 'price' ) {
                    if (a.price < b.price)
                        return -1;
                    if (a.price > b.price)
                        return 1;
                } // if ( this.sort_by == 'price' ) {

                if ( this.sort_by == 'rating' ) {
                    if (a.rating < b.rating)
                        return -1;
                    if (a.rating > b.rating)
                        return 1;
                } // if ( this.sort_by == 'rating' ) {

                if ( this.sort_by == 'name' ) {
                    if (a.name < b.name)
                        return -1;
                    if (a.name > b.name)
                        return 1;
                } // if ( this.sort_by == 'name' ) {

                return 0;
            }

            return this.$store.getters.hostels.sort(compare);
        },  // hostelsList: function() {
```

But I got this **error**:

```
app.js?dt=1556086426:98302 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort_by' of undefined"
```

**Modified Block :**
lines :

```
 console.log("this.sort_by::")
 console.log( this.sort_by )


 console.log("this::")
 console.log( this )
```

returns valid value for `sort_by` and I am not sure what must be in this: 
[image]

I suppose that reason is that `sort_by` is not accessible in compare function, but I am not sure how to pass this value?

Thanks!

Comment: what does the console log return?

Comment: Is `this` in the correct scoping?

Comment: Please look at Modified Block :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `this` in your compare function was not on equal with the `this` in your hostelsList function.

They had different scopes. So you can **either**:

1. use arrow function replace with your compare function such as

```
const compare = (a,b) =>{/*...*/}
```

2. use bind to make another function which have correct scoping such as

```
this.$store.getters.hostels.sort(compare.bind(this))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider moving `compare` to the `methods` key like so:

```
// ...
methods: {
  compare (a, b) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
computed: {
  hotelsList: function() {
    // ...

    return this.$store.getters.hostels.sort(this.compare);
  }
}
```

This will give the correct scoping to `this` inside of `compare`.